# How to Change font from values xml string folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I have been struggling to understand how to change the font family of the values/Strings.xml directory. Is there an easy way to change the font? I have added my desired font to the assets folder, but my titles are in the Strings.xml inside the values directory like this:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">FarrApp</string>

<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_search_result">Search results</string>
<string name="title_activity_login">MyApp</string>
<string name="title_activity_Calendar">Calendar</string>
<string name="title_vision">Find local events near you</string>

<!-- Strings related to login -->
<string name="prompt_email">Email</string>
<string name="prompt_password">Keyword</string>
<string name="action_sign_in">Register</string>
<string name="action_sign_in_short">Sign in</string>
<string name="action_forgot_password">Forgot password?</string>
<string name="action_forgot_submit">Reset password</string>
<string name="error_invalid_email">This email address is invalid</string>
<string name="error_invalid_password">This password is too short</string>
<string name="error_incorrect_password">This password is incorrect</string>
<string name="error_field_required">This field is required</string>
<string name="permission_rationale">"Contacts permissions are needed for providing email
    completions."
</string>
```

I am not really good at designing my app and do not have too much experience with design layouts. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What platform / program / system is this about?

Comment: Ah, ok. You should tag the question accordingly, else no one is going to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the font in your code, then apply it to your views:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Or you can do it from the xml with the attribute `android:typeface`.

Comment: I am actualy using the TextViews in this way : findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

Should I just do findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setFont?

Comment: You can write: findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setTypeface(tf);

Comment: when I apply this i get an error Typeface annot be applied to java.lang.String

 mEmailView= (EditText) mEmailView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset("calibri_bold.ttf"));

Comment: You cannot write a method in the view's initialization. Either declare it first then write the method (preferable) or write the method instantly in one line like in the previous comment I mentioned. Just do like what I posted in my answer, but change the required views and ids according to yours. Like for example, I see that you are trying to change the font for an EditText, so change the TextView to EditText in my code and write its respective id.